# Insert a message in the SSIS 2014 Catalog for reporting an error while integrating data

Tags: error-handling, ssis, sql-server-2014, catalog

I need a little help with SQL Server 2014 catalog.
I'm developping an SSIS package that will begin with a Script task that will check if the source files exist or not.
If the files needed do not exist I need to return a success as a package result but also need to write a message in the log saying that there was no source file or something..
Here is my test

```
 String FilePathEXOR = Dts.Variables["$FilePath"].Value.ToString() + "\\" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + ".csv";

        if (!File.Exists(FilePathEXOR))
        {
            Dts.Variables["User::VAR_BOOL_File_Verif_EXOM"].Value = false;//Variable that will tell if we continue or not the package execution
            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
           //Writing Some message in the catalogue saying that we've passed the package to success but there was no integration because we didn't find the Source files 

        }
```

Thank you ...

Answer (score 0):

Nearly!

Have your script return success or failure and then write to the log separately depending on success - but outside of the script task.

Info on writing to the log [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms140246.aspx).

Comment: Thank You for your answer but the problem is that I can't find any thing that alows me to write in the log. my question is how to write in there. with an SSIS compoment or something !!

Comment: Added a link for you

Comment: Thank you Jim for your response but in our project we don't have a SQL Table to Logging nore a log file we are mannaging all the packages in SSIS Catalog. then I need to write in there from SSIS package directly that's the whole problem...

Comment: OK, It's a strange requirement. I suppose you could allow the package to fail - that would show up in the log. 

I do not recommend this though.